# Symfony2 Routing annotation Error

Tags: php, symfony, web, routes

i'm working on symfony2 project, when opening index page I got route error like this :

An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Parameter "id" for route "gmjob_examination_front_view" must match "[^/]" ("4719" given).") in GmjobExaminationBundle:Front:list.html.twig at line 25.

This is my list.html.twig  line 25 :

```
<a href="{{ path(view.mainRouteName, view.mainRouteParams) }}"><h2>{{ view.title }}</h2></a>
```

This is the route annotation:

```
 * @Route("/detail-concours/{id}/{slug}", requirements = {"id" = "[^/]"})
```

here are the two methods of examination class Entity:

```
public function getMainRouteName()
{
    return 'gmjob_examination_front_view';
}

public function getMainRouteParams()
{
    return array(
        'id'   => $this->id,
        'slug' => $this->slug
    );
}
```

I appreciate your help. Thank you before.

Answer (score 0):

You have set requirements for id parameter to be `[^/]`, which essentially means: Id must match any **single** character except `/`.

You probably meant, as @Cherry said `[^/]+`. If it is so, you can remove `requirements` part all together because exactly that is the default parameter regex in Symfony Router.

So just make it:

```
* @Route("/detail-concours/{id}/{slug}")
```

Tip: If your `id` is always an integer, you probably want to make it:

```
* @Route("/detail-concours/{id}/{slug}", requirements = {"id" = "\d+"})
```